# Flink: Default Partitioning/Shuffling Strategy/Functions

Tags: apache-flink

Which strategies (hashing, sorting) does Flink use for reducing/grouping of DataSets (e.g. groupBy or reduce functions) by default? And which API-functions does Flink use for

1. partitioning during the shuffle-step and
2. sorting the elements within a partition

by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Flink uses hash-partitioning and sorting to execute reduce and groupReduce functions. In case of reduce or a combinable groupReduce, the combiner is also executed using a sort-based strategy. A hash-based combine strategy is currently under code review and will be available soon.
Note that Flink uses pipelined shuffles by default. This means that the producing sender task and the receiver-side sorter are concurrently executed.

You can partition a data set in different ways like this:

```
val data: DataSet[(String, Int)] = ...
data.partitionByHash(0) // hash-partitions on String field
data.partitionByRange(1) // range-partitions on Int field (w/ online sampling overhead)
data.partitionCustom(new MyPartitioner(), 0) // use a custom function to partition on String field
```

You can sort a partition locally as follows:

```
val data: DataSet[(String, Int)] = ...
data.sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING) // sorts partitions on String field in ascending order
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you recommend a blog post or an URL to a source code on github for further information? I am looking for a reference (source citation) for Flinks hash-partitioning/sorting-within-partition behaviour.

Comment: Not sure if there is a dedicated blog post about the behavior of the pipelined shuffle. There was a talk at last year's Flink Forward by Dongwon Kim that discussed & analyzed pipelined vs batched shuffles. Video & slides are [here](http://2015.flink-forward.org/?post_type=session). This [blog post](http://flink.apache.org/news/2015/05/11/Juggling-with-Bits-and-Bytes.html) which describes Flink's memory management and sort implementation might be helpful as well.